# NCO netcdf4 operations - ncwa (Averaging)

Tags: linux, netcdf, nco, cdo-climate

I am having trouble trying to combine three files to be averaged. I am not so sure how to even start. I have three files

"nday1.06.nc , nday1.07.nc, nday.08.nc"

each with the variables

```
"filling on), ('SST', <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
          float32 SST(time, nlat, nlon)
              long_name: Surface Potential Temperature
              units: degC
              coordinates: TLONG TLAT time
              grid_loc: 2110
              cell_methods: time: mean time: mean time: mean
              _FillValue: 9.96921e+36
          missing_value: 9.96921e+36
          unlimited dimensions: time
          current shape = (1, 2400, 3600)
```

I just need to average the SST variables and then an output file with the averages

Answer (score 2):

You need `ncra` not `ncwa`

http://nco.sourceforge.net/nco.html#ncra

```
 ncra nday1.06.nc nday1.07.nc nday.08.nc out.nc
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you! 
I was wondering, my out.nc file actually shows up as out.nc.pid44706.ncra.tmp in my directory. Will it still work as an .nc file when I use it in python?

Comment: My guess is that's the result of some error in your input files, try first with 2 files. I'm no expert in nco tools.

Comment: Yes, it should work as a .nc file and yes, Eric is right, the fact that it is there means there was an error somewhere. Suggest upgrading to latest NCO.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly, you could you use cdo, but you first need to merge the files:

`cdo mergetime nday1.06.nc nday1.07.nc nday.08.nc mergedfile.nc`

and then average:

`cdo timmean mergedfile.nc out.nc`